# Cannot create an Apple Push Notifications Certificate

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to create the Apple Push Notification Certificate through choosing Certificates and IDs, and then pressing the plus button in the developer section. But after doing this the option to create a push certificate is not there. I can only press the App Development option. Does anyone know how to fix this? [This is how it looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrz5h.png)

Comment: Check this link http://docs.buddybuild.com/docs/installing-apples-updated-intermediate-wwdr-certificate  and create new intermediate certificates

Comment: @Lalitkumar I have deleted all invalid certificates and created a new intermediate certificate, but the option is still missing.

Comment: Is it your developer account, maybe you are run out of available to create Distribution certificates? How many of them are there already created?

Comment: In the Screen, where you are asked what kind of Certificate you'd like to create. Make sure you got the "Services" Section and select "iOS Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox)" or "Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)" Your screenshot is only for Software/Apps, not for a push certificate. If this option is missing, make sure to have the "intermediate certificate" in your system's keychain